# Yii2 RBAC based on permissions

Tags: yii, yii2, yii2-rbac

I am designing a system but I need to give the admin user the power to create roles and assign a set of permissions against them.

Currently in the RBAC

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'access' => [
            'class' => AccessControl::className(),
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'actions' => ['index','view'], // these action are accessible 
                                                   //only the yourRole1 and yourRole2
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['yourRole1', 'yourRole2'],
                ],
                [    // all the action are accessible to superadmin, admin and manager
                    'allow' => true,  
                    'roles' => ['superAdmin', 'admin', 'manager'],
                ],   
            ],
        ],
    ];
}
```

However what I ideally need is

```
public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'access' => [
                'class' => AccessControl::className(),
                'rules' => [
                    [
                        'actions' => ['index','view'], 
                        'allow' => true,
                        'permission' => ['canView'],
                    ],
                    [    
                        'actions' => ['update','delete'], // these action are accessible 
                        'allow' => true,  
                        'permission' => ['canDelete', 'canUpdate'],
                    ],   
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }
```

By doing this and creating a set of permissions an admin user can then create roles, assign permissions and assign roles to users.

Does anyone know of a package for yii2 that does this?

Comment: Have youb tried with the default rbac  component in Yii2.. ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AccessControl Filter you are using already allows you to do that via the "permissions" field.

```
[
    'actions' => ['index','view'], 
    'allow' => true,
    'permissions' => ['canView'],
],
```

Check the documentation:
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-filters-accessrule.html#$permissions-detail